# React Native: LogBox not omitting warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use LogBox to ignore some log specific messages (tried also ignoring all logs) but I still get them logged on console...

```
"react-native": "0.68.2",
```

In my entry file (index.js) I have the following:

```
import { LogBox  } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(["ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types"]);
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true);
```

Neither of them work... I also added the lines inside App.js useEffect but I keep getting my unwanted log types/all logs.

Is LogBox deprecated or something? maybe I'm using the wrong syntax.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? Doesnt work on 0.71.12 as well, not trying to ignore exactly the same thing but "LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',])"

Answer (score 0):

You could read here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

// Ignore log notification by message:
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ...']);

// Ignore all log notifications:
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
```